# What's physical meaning of 2-point correlation function in holographic condensed matter?

Tags: black-holes, condensed-matter, plasma-physics, correlation-functions, ads-cft

**Background**: In AdS/CFT, we can do calculations in AdS spacetime, and get the result in CFT. When we consider RN-AdS black hole/brane, 2-point correlation functions in CFT can be obtained, which are related to polarization in plasma.

**Question**: What are the physical meanings of the following 2-point correlation functions in condensed matter physics?

$$
\langle T_{\mu\nu}J^\alpha\rangle,\,\langle T_{\mu\nu}T_{\alpha\beta}\rangle,\,\langle J^\alpha J^\beta\rangle
$$
where $T_{\mu\nu}$ is energy-momentum tensor, $J^\alpha$ is current of Maxwell field, $\mu,\nu,\alpha,\beta$ are AdS$_5$ spacetime indices.

More specifically, I want to know what's physical meanings of specific components of the above result, such as
$$
\langle T_{t t}J^t\rangle,\, \langle T_{t x}J^t\rangle,\cdots
$$

Comment: Whether is it related to piezoelectric effect? If so, how?